# Converting ampersands with str_replace

Tags: php, xhtml

We have a news site, I am trying to set up an `str_replace` to convert the occurences where `&` is pulled from the database into standards friendly `&amp;` (with the user still seeing `&`)

What happens is I get the following examples outputting on the visible site:

```
Changing World".&nbsp; The report
Copper &amp; Gold
```

instead of the expected space or ampersand. The data is being pulled from a mysqldb with text fields. Where am I going wrong?

My code is:

```
function textfix($text){
    $find = array('&', '<br>');
    $replace = array('&amp;', '<br />');
    $newtext = str_replace($find, $replace, $text);
    return $newtext;
}
```

the html stuff is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

Comment: I want the end user to see & but the html code for it to be &amp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has nothing to do with `&nbsp;` however if you have `&nbsp;` in your `$text`  it will be changed to `&amp;nbsp;`

also tell us what do you see in source-code of that html snippet

Comment: Why sir I do believe you have nailed it:

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` functions instead of trying to convert the ampersands.

Comment: I am pulling this as a press release so occasionally there may be links in the text. What I'm trying to do is convert the &'s stored in the db into &amp; for the sake of standards. When I am doing that though it is displaying the &amp; instead of converting back to a &

Comment: I think your issue may be caused by &amp; being already stored in the database field.  You should only replace the ampersands that are not part of encoded entities (i.e. not &nbsp;, &amp;, &quot;, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

using `str_replace()` will tell your program to mercilessly covert any & to `&amp;` even in places where you need it, like with `&nbsp;` or whatever.

I'd suggest using `preg_replace()` and using regular expressions such as `/&[^\w]/` to make sure you're only replacing independent ampersands.

using `preg_replace()` you can use the arrays as normal, and the parameters are the same as with `str_replace()`, but you should use regular expressions as the string values of the find array.

See [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for more details.